# Respect rownames in addition

Tags: r

I come from Python Pandas, so I am used to dataframes respecting row names upon manipulation.
R seems to work differently:

```
x = rbind(c(0, 0), c(1, 1))
rownames(x) = c("a", "b")

y = rbind(c(0, 0), c(1, 1))
rownames(y) = c("b", "a")
```

Then

```
> x + y
  [,1] [,2]
a    0    0
b    2    2
```

This seems borderline dangerous to me; especially since the new data frame again has rownames `a` and `b`.
What is the reason for this bevahior? How can I tell R to respect row names?

**Edit:** The problem does not go away if I set `x = data.frame(x)` and `y = data.frame(y)`.

Comment: You're working with `matrices` here (think numpy arrays) not `data.frames`

Comment: Then what's the point of the row names?

Comment: This: `x['a',]`. Data.frames in R do not work like dataframes in Pandas, there is no column or row name matching like in pandas.

Comment: Row names are usually not used for indexing when dealing with dataframes in R.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here a solution using `data.frame` instead of `matrix` :

Two data.frame `x` and `y`

```
x = data.frame(rbind(c(0, 0), c(1, 2)))
y = data.frame(rbind(c(0, 0), c(1, 1)))
```

Assign colnames and rownames (the order of columns and rows is reversed)

```
rownames(x) = c("a", "b")
rownames(y) = c("b", "a") 
colnames(x) = c("A", "B")
colnames(y) = c("B", "A")

x
  A B
a 0 0
b 1 2

y
  B A
b 0 0
a 1 1
```

Your desired output:

```
x+y[match(rownames(x),rownames(y)),match(colnames(x),colnames(y))]
  A B
a 1 1
b 1 2
```

Comment: That shifts the problem to columns ... suppose I have `rownames(x) = c("a", "b"), rownames(y) = c("b", "a")` and `colnames(x) = c("A", "B"), colnames(y) = c("B", "A")`. I find it hard to believe that before adding two data frames with the same row names and column names, I should have to check whether the order of rows and columns is identical in both.

Comment: Yes sorry, code changed according to this point adding the match of columns in the sum

Comment: No, that is not the desired output. `x["a", "A"] + y["a", "A"] = 1` but `(x+y)["a", "A"] = 0`.

Comment: Ok, maybe here we are. Answer changed.

Answer (score 0):

First off, these are matrices, not data frames, but they both have your issue of performing matrix calculations. The reason is with R, matrix calculations are based on using the same row numbers instead of the same row names. It then looks at rownames afterwards, using the rownames from the first matrix in the equation. For example:

```
> y+x
  [,1] [,2]
b    0    0
a    2    2
```

Now the rownames are based on `y` instead of `x`.

If you want to base the additions on the rownames, you should specify the rownames.

```
> x["a",] + y["a",]
[1] 1 1
> x["b",] + y["b",]
[1] 1 1
```

Knowing this, it should be easy to generate your desired matrix.

```
> rbind(a = x["a",] + y["a",], b = x["b",] + y["b",])
  [,1] [,2]
a    1    1
b    1    1
```

Comment: What would that look like for an arbitrary number of rows?